# How to access .NET classes within Powershell?

Tags: .net, powershell, azure, azure-eventhub

I am new in the Powershell and Azure (C/C++ background) world and I want to write a PowerShell script which monitors an Azure Event Hub. One way (and so far the only way I've found) to solve this is by using the .NET classes from `Microsoft.​Azure.​Event​Hubs.​Processor`. I assume the code to create an instance of the `EventProcessorHost` class would look something like this:

```
$eventPHost = [Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor]::EventProcessorHost($AZR_EVENT_HUB_PATH, $AZR_CONSUMER_GRP_NAME, $AZR_EVENT_HUB_CONNECTION_STR, $AZR_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STR, $AZR_LEASE_CONTAINER_NAME);
```

However, the namespace `Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor` is unknown to PowerShell and it seems that I am doing something wrong or missing something. At this point I am not sure if my code is invalid or I am missing some .NET SDK or something. Also I couldn't find any examples which are similar to this.

Could anyone lead me in the right direction please? I am kind of stuck with no idea in which direction to go.

Comment: Can you copy this DLL in the directory from where you're running the PS script?

Comment: Azure has its own selection of Powershell modules. Have you [read the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/overview?view=azurermps-4.0.0) yet?

Comment: @vonPryz Thanks, but these only support the Resource Management for Event Hubs, not allowing them to be monitored.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to download .dll into powershell session:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("c:\script\name.dll")
```

Comment: `Add-Type -AssemblyName` is the preferred way to load .Net assemblies.

Comment: I get the following console output: 
`GAC    Version        Location ---    -------        -------- False  v4.0.30319     C:\Users\abc\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor\1.0.1\lib\net451\Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Process...`

However, when I try to access [Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor] it says: "Unable to find type [Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor]."

Answer (score 1):

You can load the assembly using Add-Type:
For e.g.

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\assemblies\name_of_assembly.dll"
```

Comment: `Add-Type -Path "<path>"`


Doesn't work for me: `Add-Type : Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.`

I am using PS version 5.1.14393.1198